# Array to string conversion error using php v7.0.13

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel, php-7

I have the following code in my laravel controller file.

```
$j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available = ($j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available+$totalincrement);
```

and I am getting the following error.

> ErrorException in BookingsController.php line 325: Array to string
> conversion in BookingsController.php line 325 at
> HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Array to string conversion',
> 'D:\XAMPP\htdocs\lara\app\Http\Controllers\BookingsController.php',
> '325', array('request' => object(Request), 'id' => '0', 'rules' =>
> array(), 'validator' => object(Validator), 'data' => array('_kpnID' =>
> '153290', '_kfnTourID' => '2', '_kfdTourDate' => '2017-03-16',
> 'nAdults' => '2', 'nChildren' => '1', 'nInfants' => '0', 'nBabies' =>
> '2', 'nFOC' => '2', 'nPriceAdult' => '74.25', 'nPriceChild' => '49.5',
> 'nPriceInfant' => '0', 'nPriceBaby' => '0', 'nTotalPrice' => '148.5',
> 'tGuestName' => 'Yuhiko Nishioka', 'tGuestOrigin' => 'Unknown',
> 'tEnquirySourceWhat' => 'Unknown', 'tStatus' => 'Confirmed',
> '_kfnAgentID' => '0', '_kfnPersonID' => '0', '_kfnInvoiceID' => '0',
> 'nAgentCommissionPercent' => '0', 'nDiscount_percent' => '0',
> 'nDiscount_fixed' => '0', 'tNotes' => '4WD Tour package/Rezdy, applied
> discount', 'tInitials' => 'JD', 'CreatedOn' => '2017-01-21 15:08:00',
> 'ModifiedOn' => '2017-01-21 15:10:00', 'tTicketNumber' => 'Rezdy',
> '_kfnOrganisationID' => '0'), 'schedule' => object(Collection),
> 'j_decode' => object(stdClass), 'update_id_data' => object(stdClass),
> 'totalincrement' => '3')) in BookingsController.php line 325

Interesting part that it's working on the linux server when I upload it to my host. I have PHP Version 7.0.13 on localhost and PHP Version 5.6.30 on the server.

How can this line cause an Array to string conversion error?

I am not willing to downgrade my php version on localhost as I have other codes that php5 is not supporting.

The whole code in controller:

```
$rules = $this->validateForm();
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  
if ($validator->passes()) {
$data = $this->validatePost( $request );

$schedule = DB::table('schedule')
        ->where('id','=',$data['_kfnTourID'])
        ->get();
        
        if(isset($_SESSION['bookingiddata']))
        {
            print_r  ($j_decode= json_decode($schedule[0]->data));
            $update_id_data = json_decode($_SESSION['bookingiddata']);
            
            $totalincrement = $update_id_data->nAdults+$update_id_data->nChildren+$update_id_data->nInfants+$update_id_data->nFOC;
            //$j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available = ($j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available+$totalincrement);
            $j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']['available'] = ($j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']['available']+$totalincrement);
            ($j_decode->$data)['_kfdTourDate']->status = "available";
```

Also `print_r $j_encode = json_encode($j_decode);` prints me the following

> {"2017-02-13":{"available":1,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"available"},"2017-02-14":{"available":1,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"available"},"2017-02-08":{"available":0,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"booked"},"2017-02-12":{"available":0,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"booked"},"2017-02-10":{"available":0,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"booked"},"2017-02-15":{"available":0,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"booked"},"2017-02-16":{"available":0,"bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":0,"promo":0,"status":"booked"}...

Comment: Is $j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available an array?

Comment: it's hard to maintain without your actual arrays structure;

Comment: it seems like you're accessing an unknown variable from `_kfdTourDate`, this is returning a string `2017-03-16`. maybe the reason why there's no error your linux server is because the error reporting is disabled.

Comment: Woaww @Semi-Friends thanks! That's exactly whats happens. Thank you for the succession. I will play with it and will let you know the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, as mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)

in php 5.6.3 , it's allowed to use this expression:

```
echo $json_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available;
```

so , you are trying to access the value of `$data['_kfdTourDate']` which is element in `$json_decode` object

for example: https://3v4l.org/i9Q7p

---

in php 7,

> Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods will now be
>   evaluated **strictly in left-to-right order**, as opposed to the previous
>   mix of special cases. The table below shows how the order of
>   evaluation has changed.

so, the interpreter will interpret this code as follow:

```
echo $json_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available;
// first , give me the value $json_decode->$data,
// then choose the _kfdTourDate key
```

and to solve this, you need to :

```
echo $json_decode->{$data['_kfdTourDate']}->available;
```

to tell php that `$data['_kfdTourDate']` is just a value;

Comment: Unbelievable! It was so simple. Thank you for detailed explanation. I am sure that lots of people like me will benefit from this post.

Answer (score 1):

There were some order-of-operations changes in PHP7 (see [Changes to the handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect)). I suspect you might need to mess around with some parentheses within `$j_decode->$data['_kfdTourDate']->available` to make it evaluate in the order you want.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It is very useful. I will try to change the parentheses and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: updated my post. Could you please check it? It might give more idea about my problem  I played with parentheses didn't work.